# Can Telegram, Whatsapp and Discord groups be addictive?

Tags: addiction

Can groups on Whatsapp, Telegram and Discord potentially addictive? They provide powerful social rewards like being constantly connected to a large number of people and endless streams of content. Also they provide fodder for repeated cue reward cycles when you're constantly checking for updates.

Comment: Similar to [Facebook dopamine kick - any proof?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/19184/7001)

Comment: The thing is these are not included under addictive 'social media', rather text messaging tools mainly.

Comment: Welcome. You might wish to update the question and add background to this difference you pose here in the comments.